# request url and get encrypted text

Tags: php, encryption, request

I have cache files in mysite and I want to get all of them from remote. I write small app in my site, this echos encrypted text with query string. Getting text from remote ok but text has some bad chars or somethings is wrong. 
My remote Code :

```
$req = file_get_contents($website.'Cache.php?cacheid='.$filename.'&action=getContent');
        $req = trim($req);
        $req = str_replace (array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '', $req);

        $decryptedText = decrypt(trim($req),'mypass') ;

    array_push($fileNameTexts,'<div style="color:red;">'.$filename.'</div><div>'.$decryptedText.'</div>');
}
$template->data['decryptedCaches'] = $fileNameTexts;   
}


 function decrypt($encrypted, $password, $salt='mysalt') {

     **file_put_contents(DIR_SYSTEM.'test'.'.txt',$encrypted );**

     $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);
     $iv = base64_decode(substr($encrypted, 0, 22) . '==');
     $encrypted = substr($encrypted, 22);
     $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0\4");
     $hash = substr($decrypted, -32);
     $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -32);
     if (md5($decrypted) != $hash) return false;
     return $decrypted;

}
```

file_put_contents save correct data but not return true decrypted data.

When I try

```
$decryptedText = decrypt(trim('kjsfkdsjflkdsflksdjfsl'),'mypass') ;
```

It runs correct. I try trim and str_replace for some chars but it doesnt work.Has Returned data from request  any bad char ? What is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You must convert all bad caracters but base64 not work.

The solution : convert your string in hex. 
Instead of `base64_encode` use `bin2hex($yourvalue)` and decrypt this with `pack("H*" ,$string);`

I hope my answer can be help you.